# Can PHP parse this data?

Tags: php

Data like:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";s:7:"message";s:0:"";s:5:"medal";N;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}
```

and what's this datatype?

Comment: unserialize function in PHP

Comment: it looks **sort** of like JSON

Comment: @zack6849 no bro, its a serialized array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't have been that hard if you tried

```
print_r(unserialize('a:2:{s:9:"usergroup";s:0:"";s:6:"verify";s:0:"";}'));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [usergroup] => 
    [verify] => 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

The datatype is a non-standard protocol which exists only within the `php-src` scripting language.

To properly create a PHP value from a stored representation you would use the [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)` function provided by the SPL.

`unserialize('a:2:{s:9:"usergroup";s:0:"";s:6:"verify";s:0:"";}');`

[`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value.